# Proving continuity of norm-function in 2 variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

Let $M:= \{x = (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \; | \; x_1 > \sqrt{|x_2|}\}$ and define

$f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x):= \frac{x_1}{\|x\|_2}$ for $x = (x_1,x_2) \in M$, where $\|\cdot\|_2$ means the Euclidean norm.

Show, that f can be extended continuously in $(0,0)$.

---

So my guess is that $f$ can be extended continuously to the value "1".
Therefore, I have to use the $\epsilon-\delta$-criterion and hence I have to show $\|f(x) - 1\| < \epsilon$ for any given $\epsilon > 0$ and assumption $\|x\| < \delta$.

Because $\|x\|_2 \ge x_1$ and $x_1 > \sqrt{|x_2|}$, I get

$|f(x) - 1| = \left|\frac{x_1}{\|x\|_2} - 1\right| = \left|\frac{x_1 - \|x\|_2}{\|x\|_2}\right| = \frac{\|x\|_2 - x_1}{\|x\|_2} < \frac{\|x\|_2 - \sqrt{|x_2|}}{\|x\|_2}$

How can the resulting term be estimated, so that $\frac{\|x\|_2 - \sqrt{|x_2|}}{\|x\|_2} < \epsilon$ under the assumption $\|x\|_2 < \delta$ or maybe $\|x\| < \delta$ for any other norm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write $(x,y)$ instead.

\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}-1\right|&=\left|\dfrac{x-\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\right|\\
&=\left|\dfrac{-y^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}(x+\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}})}\right|,
\end{align*}
note that
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{|y|}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\leq 1 
\end{align*}
for $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$.

Therefore, for $(x,y)\in M$, $x>\sqrt{|y|}\geq 0$ and hence
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}-1\right|&\leq\dfrac{|y|}{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\\
&\leq\dfrac{|y|}{\sqrt{|y|}+\sqrt{|y|+y^{2}}}\\
&\leq\dfrac{|y|}{\sqrt{|y|}+\sqrt{|y|}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{|y|}\\
&\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
as $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$, $(x,y)\in M$.

Comment: How could the $\epsilon-\delta$-criterion be applied here for $\|(x,y)\|<\delta$? Maybe using the maximum norm, which would mean $|x| < \delta$ and $|y| < \delta$, but in this case $\sqrt{|y|} > |y|$ for $0 < |y| < 1$ ? Otherwise $\|(x,y)\|_2 < \delta$ would mean $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta$, but again, $\sqrt{|y|} > \sqrt{y^2}$ for $0 < y < 1$ ?

Comment: That is easy. For $\|(x,y)\|<\epsilon^{2}$, then $|y|\leq\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}<\epsilon^{2}$ and so $\sqrt{|y|}<\epsilon$ and hence $(1/2)\sqrt{|y|}<\epsilon$ too.

Comment: That works out perfectly! I voted for and accepted your answer.